# SQL database browser with ability to navigate to related records

Tags: mysql, sql, ide

Would you be so kind to propose some SQL database browser, which allows to navigate to:

- tables/rows that this row reffers to
- tables/rows that are reffered by this row

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use NAVICAT, it's very effective.

You can enter your owns query's (as related to your question) or even use a visual query builder.

[Navicat website](http://www.navicat.com/)

Comment: I haven't found ability to find all records that refer to a certain row.